# Creating a custom scala inspection in IntelliJ for complex pattern

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, anonymous-function, code-inspection

I would like to create a custom inspection in IntelliJ to warn the use of a return statement inside an anonymous function in scala. For example, lets suppose I want to count the number of values higher than 3 in a Seq (in a very ugly way):

```
val seq = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

def foo(s: Seq[Int]): Int = {
   s.map(x => {
      if (x > 3) 
          return 1
      0
   }).count()
}

foo(seq)
```

This code is wrong, the mistake here is that the `return` statement will cause the named `foo` function to return 1, instead of returning 1 in the anonymous function `x => {...}`.

The code I'm working on is composed of a lot of files, and I already found this mistake several times, but there are too many files and I cannot examine them all manually.

I'm working with IntelliJ-idea, and I know that it is possible to create custom inspection rules with the search and replace template option, but for such complex inspection, I havn't been able to produce the template nor to find any help on how to create it.

Thanks in advance for any help/hints !

Comment: It would appear that, as of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2, these custom inspections are not enabled for Scala. Did you find any solution to your problem?